# Limiting Condition(s) for a Charged Sphere in a Uniform Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I am attempting to understand a solution that has non-physical limits.

**Context:**

I'm solving for a conducting sphere of radius $R$ that is immersed in a constant and uniform electric field and that has a charge $q_0$ placed on its surface. I thought about doing it the easy way first and assumed that I could unapologetically steal Jackson's solution for the potential of a grounded sphere in this same instance and add a term that took into account the free surface charge on the sphere:

1. Jackson's solution for grounded sphere in E-field: $$V_p(r,\phi) = -E_0\left(r-\frac{R^3}{r^2}\right)\cos\theta$$
2. Potential for a sphere of uniformly distributed charge: $$V_s(r,\phi) = \frac{kq_0}{r}.$$

Total potential of system:

$$V(r,\phi) = V_p(r,\phi) + V_s(r,\phi) = \frac{kq_0}{r} - E_0\left(r-\frac{R^3}{r^2}\right).$$

The subsequent charge distribution is then:
$$\sigma = -\epsilon_0\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}\Bigr|_{r=R} = \frac{q_0}{4 \pi R^2} +3E_0\epsilon_0 \cos(\theta).$$

Now what I want to know is how many electrons have moved between each half of the sphere. To do this, I integrate over each half surface:

\begin{align}
Q_{H^+} &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sigma R^2 \sin(\theta) \,d\theta d\phi, \\
Q_{H^-} &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \sigma R^2 \sin(\theta) \,d\theta d\phi.
\end{align}

This yields
$$Q_{H^{\pm}} = \frac{q_0}{2} \pm 3\pi R^2E_0\epsilon_0,$$
and so
$$q_0 = Q_{H^+} + Q_{H^-}.$$

On the face of it, this seems to be an intuitive and correct solution set. This also looks fine and makes sense when we see $E \rightarrow 0$.

**The issue:**

However, this solution quickly becomes non-physical even when plugging in very reasonable values. Let us input a discrete parameter for the charge $q_0$ by saying there is $N_e$ electrons on the surface. Thus, $N_e = \frac{q_0}{e} = N_{e^+} + N_{e^-}$, where $e$ is the electron charge. And more specifically, let us say $N_e = 1000$ electrons. I also will redefine $E_0$ as $\frac{V_0}{d}$ as this may pertain more directly to what variables can be altered in an experiment (i.e. two conducting plates separated by a distance $d$ and whose potential difference is $V_0$). We don't need to plug in some limit for $V_0$ such that it goes to infinity to make it nonphysical, but even just inputting some experimentally reasonable and discrete value such as $1000 \ \rm V$ already breaks the solution. Assuming each parameter is defined as follows:

\begin{align}
d &= 0.15, \\
V_0 &= 1000, \\
R &= 25\times 10^{-6}, \\
\epsilon_0 &= 8.8542\times 10^{-12}, \\
e &= 1.602\times 10^{-19}.
\end{align}

Plugging these into $Q_{H^+}$ and $Q_{H^-}$ we get:

$$N_{e^+} = \frac{Q_{H^+}}{e} \approx 2670$$
$$N_{e^-} = \frac{Q_{H^-}}{e} \approx -1670$$

This generates more electrons than are specified by the initial condition and creates negative solutions, making them nonphysical.

**Current thoughts:**

I have stared at this for a while and think that the problem may have something to do with one of three reasons.

1. It could be that the approximated potential I used is incorrect (specifically the part for the free charge) and that it is more complicated.
2. The potential is incorrect for this instance because I need to use the Greene's function method instead of the image charge method to solve for this potential. Perhaps only method of images works when this is a grounded sphere?
3. I need to add physics that are not being accounted for in the problem, such as knowing that these free electrons cannot be stacked on top of each other and that they're exhibiting forces between each other to keep them at a maximum density value. Or they may break the surface work function and escape the surface before they get within some atomic radius of each other. So maybe I need to calculate the minimum distance these electrons can be near each other as a function of input voltage (V). The reason I don't think it's this reason though is that I would assume that information is being accounted for already by the polarization potential term Jackson solved. But I'm not entirely sure.

Would appreciate input or ideas.

Comment: The only electrons at your disposition are not only the ones making up for the excess charge. You have other electrons in the bulk of the material that came along with the atoms it is made of (so rather of the order of $N_A = 10^{23}$). Take the neutral case $q_0=0$ for example. Your conductor will still exhibit polarisation using only the electrons it has at hand.

Comment: @Ipz I thought about that occurring and that is what may be happening for where the half that is getting additional electrons (Them being pulled in from the interior) but it does not account for why the solution for the half of the sphere where the electrons are moving away becomes negative. It should be at the very least, zero. So I am thinking this solution just doesn't have enough physics involved to explain that and I am not sure how to include that.

Comment: I had an idea of getting another solution that looks at the force being generated across the surface as a function of $\phi$ and $E_0$ maybe. Then looking for an equilibrium state between the inter-electron forces and the force from the polarization effect. However, as I said in thought 3, I would think this is already being accounted for by the current solution. Or I could simply say that the side that is losing electrons on the surface is forced to go to zero and that additional electrons from the interior just move and so we don't need to do any more math here which I would be fine with :)

Comment: I don’t understand you objection in the first comment. A negative number of electrons just means a deficit of them, which is still physically valid (they leave behind the positive charge of the fixed nuclei+bound electrons).

Comment: For your second comment, first attempt, the inter electron force is already taken into account in the Laplace equation and the boundary equations (electric force countered by pressure at the conductor’s boundary).

Comment: For your second comment second attempt, just setting $Q_{H-}=0$ would leave the system unbalance and is not a valid solution

Comment: So even if I am specifying that the system has $N_e$ electrons, the solution holds some arbitrary amount built into it that undermines the condition I specified? How does that hold in reality where there is a discreet count? Also, if I do specify the electron count to now be on the order of $10^23$ it seems like there are very few electrons that will move because of the external field. A negligible amount even to create an internal counter field which seems unintuitive.

Comment: Or is it, because it is also including the polarized atom-electron pairs inside the material too? Which is why there are not many surface electrons moving?